# How to create new core 2.0 project?

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I've just reinstalled VS 2017 15.6.2 using web installer and tried to create new 
empty Asp.net core 2.0 project.
But when i open it i got error:

> Project file is incomplete. Expected imports are missing.

My version of SDK is 2.1.101, which was installed with visual studio. 
I selected web and .net core development features during install, what am i missing?

I tried to create empty core console app and everything works fine.

**UPDATE**
this error is related to folder structure

```
C:\Novatek.Monitoring.WebUI // no errors
C:\Svn\Monitoring\trunk\Novatek.Monitoring.WebUI // Project file is incomplete. Expected imports are missing.
```

Comment: "reinstalled" is raising a flag...  Look in Sol Explorer if you can see what it is missing. The Restart PC, Repair, ... Dispare.

Comment: @Henk Holterman i've installed all new window 10 and new VS 2017. I tried to repair and restarted couple times.

Comment: See if any of this helps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/, e.g. the section "Create an ASP.NET Core MVC web app"

Answer (score 0):

Try follow this tutorial:

https://www.asp.net/get-started

Remember to check your dotnet-core version with 'dotnet --version'

Comment: i use visual studio, version is 2.1.101

Comment: Yes, I know, but try to make solution with command line and then open it with visual studio

Comment: it really helped, but what's the problem with VS?

Comment: It seem's it's problem with my folders structure, i moved my old project to drive's root and it opened fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this simple and basic steps :) This link will help get started in creating your first dynamic ASP.NET Core MVC Web App connected to MS SQL Server.

https://deanilvincent.github.io/2018/01/12/steps-in-creating-simple-but-dynamic-powerful-web-app-using-asp-net-core-mvc-connected-to-a-database/